# How can I make character to crouch and also moving faster when left shift key is holding down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the Input settings in the editor there is no crouch and no left shift to make the player moving faster.

This is my script name character controller. attached to the FPSController(Player).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        transform.Translate(0, jumpForce * Input.GetAxis("Jump") * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

I want to add crouch and left shift for faster moving.

This script is only for controlling the mouse looking around and lock state of the mouse cursor attached to the main camera(Player child).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;
    public bool mouseDown = false;
    public bool cursorLock = false;
    public HandleMouseCursor handleMouseCursor;

    GameObject character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if(cursorLock == false)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            handleMouseCursor.setMouse();
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && mouseDown == true)
        {
            MouseLook();
        }
        else
        {
            if (mouseDown == false)
            {
                MouseLook();
            }
        }
    }

    private void MouseLook()
    {
        if (cursorLock == false)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            handleMouseCursor.setMouse();
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change speed of your movement in your `CharacterController` script.
Just create a variable for crouch speed and multiplay it to your translation vector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 20;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        float finalMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;

        // you can add more IF statements for more actions like walking, running, jumping,...
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.KeyCode.LeftShift))
              finalMoveSpeed = crouchSpeed ;

        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * finalMoveSpeed ;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * finalMoveSpeed ;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        transform.Translate(0, jumpForce * Input.GetAxis("Jump") * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```